# star rating con ajax y jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código html que me muestra las estrellas en pantalla.

```
 <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="rating.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Rating CSS">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container" style="margin-top:35px">
        <div class="ratings">
            <input type="radio" name="star" id="rating" value="1">
            <input type="radio" name="star" id="rating" value="2">
            <input type="radio" name="star" id="rating" value="3">
            <input type="radio" name="star" id="rating" value="4">
            <input type="radio" name="star" id="rating" value="5">
        </div>
        <br>
        <span class="info"></span>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="rating.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.ratings').rating(function(vote, event) {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'insrating.php',
                data: {
                    vote: vote

                }//línea 42
            }).done(function(info) { 
                $('.info').html("Your vote: <b>" + info + "</b>")
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

Esto me muestra las 5 estrellas en la pantalla. Al pasar el ratón por encima, las va pintando como su fuese una calificación, ya que esa es la misión.

Lo que quiero lograr es que por ejemplo si hago click en 4 estrellas, salga un mensaje diciendo: "your vote: 4".

Aquí muestro el php a donde lo mando:

```
    <?php
echo $_POST['vote'];
?>
```

Y estos son los errores que me salen en la consola. No entiendo los errores "anchorElement" o de "enlace":

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(...).done is not a function
    at Object.callback ((index):42)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.click (rating.js:1)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.handle (jquery.min.js:19)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:19)
```

Alguien puede ayudarme??

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la version de jquery que estas usando no tiene definido la el metodo done en el objeto ajax...

vas a tener que implemntarlo asi de la manera tradicional .

```
$.ajax({

url='asd',
type:'post',
data:{lo q vas a enviar},
success:function(request){
  alert(request)
},
complete:function(data){
}
})
```

lo que iria en tu funcion done lo pones en success  y listo o en complete..

si no queres hacerlo asi actualiza la version del jquery descargate la version nueva y remplazala.
entra a la pagian de jquery busca el enlace de la cdn ycambialo donde esta incluyendo tu jquery.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! He actualizado la versión de jQuery y parece que algo ha arreglado porque ahora solo me devuelve un error:

`jquery.min.js:2 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///Users/usuario/Sites/star_rating/insrating.php' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

Comment: He probado también con la manera que me has dicho combinando la versión de jQuery antigua y la nueva, pero tampoco funciona. Lo tengo así:

Comment: `/*último div aquí*/
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="rating.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url = 'insrating.php',
            data: {
                vote: vote
            },
            success: function(info) {
                alert(info)
            },
            complete: function(data) {
                $('.info').html("Your vote: <b>" + info + "</b>")
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>`

Comment: y me devuelve este error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer` ocurre justo en donde he puesto la url (insrating.php, o sea, el controlador a donde quiero que vaya).

Comment: aver... porque estas haciendo url= y no, esto un error de sintaxis ,, la forma correcta seria url: y los dos puntos porque los parametros del metodo ajax es un objeto json y la sintaxis para un json es {clave:valor} y vos tenes {url=' tu url '}. tenes que remplazaar el signo igual =  por los dos puntos :